# find the ranks of elements in a vector from another longer vector in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a short vector `v1=c(1,3,4,7,9)` and another short vector `v2=c(3,4,10,12,9)`. The combined "long" vector is `v=c(1,3,3,4,4,7,9,9,10,12)`. Now I want to find the rank of each of the elements in `v1` (i.e. 1,3,4,7,9) in the long vector `v`. How can I efficiently do that in R? Thanks!

Comment: which element do you want to match? There are multiple matches for some elements in `v`

Comment: @alexwhan thanks! in case of ties, return the average rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
sapply(v1,function(x) mean(which(x==v)))
# [1] 1.0 2.5 4.5 6.0 7.5
```